# Could not open the editor: An unexpected exception was thrown

Tags: java, eclipse, bpel

I was on a plugin for Eclipse and now all of a sudden i cannot open the BPEL Workflows anymore.
I get this error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
 at sun.text.normalizer.ReplaceableUCharacterIterator.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at sun.text.normalizer.UCharacterIterator.getInstance(Unknown Source)
 at sun.text.normalizer.NormalizerBase.setText(Unknown Source)
 at java.text.CollationElementIterator.setText(Unknown Source)
 at java.text.RuleBasedCollator.compare(Unknown Source)
 at org.eclipse.bpel.ui.BPELEditor$8.compare(BPELEditor.java:1173)
 at org.eclipse.bpel.ui.BPELEditor$8.compare(BPELEditor.java:1)
 at java.util.TreeMap.put(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.TreeSet.add(Unknown Source)
 at org.eclipse.bpel.ui.BPELEditor.createPaletteDependentActions(BPELEditor.java:1195)
 at org.eclipse.bpel.ui.BPELEditor.createPaletteDependentActions(BPELEditor.java:1188)
 at org.eclipse.bpel.ui.BPELEditor.createPaletteDependentActions(BPELEditor.java:1180)
 at org.eclipse.bpel.ui.BPELEditor.init(BPELEditor.java:1539)
 at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.addPage(MultiPageEditorPart.java:237)
 at org.eclipse.bpel.ui.BPELMultipageEditorPart.createDesignPage(BPELMultipageEditorPart.java:459)
 at org.eclipse.bpel.ui.BPELMultipageEditorPart.createPages(BPELMultipageEditorPart.java:515)
 at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.createPartControl(MultiPageEditorPart.java:348)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPartHelper(EditorReference.java:670)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(EditorReference.java:465)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:595)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorAreaHelper.setVisibleEditor(EditorAreaHelper.java:271)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.setVisibleEditor(EditorManager.java:1429)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager$5.runWithException(EditorManager.java:942)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:134)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4041)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3660)
 at org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor.openWindows(WorkbenchAdvisor.java:803)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$31.runWithException(Workbench.java:1567)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:134)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4041)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3660)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2548)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2438)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:671)
 at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:664)
 at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:115)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:620)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:575)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1408)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1384)
```

i really never understand these error messages.
What exactly is the error here. i also get some more information on the console:

```
 java.net.MalformedURLException
        at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.bpel.ui.palette.simtech.FragmentUIObjectFactory.getSmallImageDescriptor(FragmentUIObjectFactory.java:159)
        at org.eclipse.bpel.ui.util.BPELCreationToolEntry.<init>(BPELCreationToolEntry.java:37)
        at org.eclipse.bpel.ui.palette.PaletteFactory.registerFragment(PaletteFactory.java:269)
        at org.eclipse.bpel.ui.palette.PaletteFactory.createBPELPaletteEntries(PaletteFactory.java:182)
        at org.eclipse.bpel.ui.palette.PaletteFactory.contributeItems(PaletteFactory.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.bpel.common.ui.palette.GraphicalEditorWithPalette.createPalette(GraphicalEditorWithPalette.java:220)
        at org.eclipse.bpel.common.ui.palette.GraphicalEditorWithPalette.getPaletteRoot(GraphicalEditorWithPalette.java:144)
        at org.eclipse.gef.ui.parts.GraphicalEditorWithFlyoutPalette.setEditDomain(GraphicalEditorWithFlyoutPalette.java:145)
        at org.eclipse.bpel.ui.BPELEditor.<init>(BPELEditor.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.bpel.ui.BPELMultipageEditorPart.createDesignPage(BPELMultipageEditorPart.java:445)
        at org.eclipse.bpel.ui.BPELMultipageEditorPart.createPages(BPELMultipageEditorPart.java:515)
        at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.createPartControl(MultiPageEditorPart.java:348)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPartHelper(EditorReference.java:670)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(EditorReference.java:465)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:595)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorAreaHelper.setVisibleEditor(EditorAreaHelper.java:271)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.setVisibleEditor(EditorManager.java:1429)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager$5.runWithException(EditorManager.java:942)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
........
org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:575)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1408)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1384)
    !SESSION 2015-02-07 20:21:00.866 -----------------------------------------------
    eclipse.buildId=M20110210-1200
    java.version=1.6.0_45
    java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
    BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=de_DE
    Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.platform.ide
    Command-line arguments:  -product org.eclipse.platform.ide -data D:\eclipseWorkspaces\AKTUELL/../runtime-EclipseApplication -dev file:D:/eclipseWorkspaces/AKTUELL/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/Eclipse Application/dev.properties -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -consoleLog

    !ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2015-02-07 20:21:09.209
    !MESSAGE Unable to create editor ID org.eclipse.bpel.ui.bpeleditor: An unexpected exception was thrown.
    !STACK 0
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at sun.text.normalizer.ReplaceableUCharacterIterator.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at sun.text.normalizer.UCharacterIterator.getInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.text.normalizer.NormalizerBase.setText(Unknown Source)
        at java.text.CollationElementIterator.setText(Unknown Source)
        at java.text.RuleBasedCollator.compare(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.bpel.ui.BPELEditor$8.compare(BPELEditor.java:1173)
        at org.eclipse.bpel.ui.BPELEditor$8.compare(BPELEditor.java:1)
        at java.util.TreeMap.put(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.TreeSet.add(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.bpel.ui.BPELEditor.createPaletteDependentActions(BPELEditor.java:1195)
        at org.eclipse.bpel.ui.BPELEditor.createPaletteDependentActions(BPELEditor.java:1188)
        at org.eclipse.bpel.ui.BPELEditor.createPaletteDependentActions(BPELEditor.java:1180)
        at org.eclipse.bpel.ui.BPELEditor.init(BPELEditor.java:1539)
        at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.addPage(MultiPageEditorPart.java:237)
        at org.eclipse.bpel.ui.BPELMultipageEditorPart.createDesignPage(BPELMultipageEditorPart.java:459)
        at org.eclipse.bpel.ui.BPELMultipageEditorPart.createPages(BPELMultipageEditorPart.java:515)
        at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.createPartControl(MultiPageEditorPart.java:348)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPartHelper(EditorReference.java:670)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(EditorReference.java:465)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:595)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorAreaHelper.setVisibleEditor(EditorAreaHelper.java:271)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.setVisibleEditor(EditorManager.java:1429)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager$5.runWithException(EditorManager.java:942)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:134)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4041)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3660)
        at org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor.openWindows(WorkbenchAdvisor.java:803)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$31.runWithException(Workbench.java:1567)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:134)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4041)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3660)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2548)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2438)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:671)
        at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:664)
        at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:115)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:575)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1408)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1384)

    !ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 2 2 2015-02-07 20:21:09.241
    !MESSAGE Ignored attempt to add saveable that was already registered
    !STACK 0
    org.eclipse.core.runtime.AssertionFailedException: unknown saveable: org.eclipse.ui.internal.DefaultSaveable@178e964 from part: org.eclipse.ui.internal.ErrorEditorPart@178e964
........................org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:575)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1408)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1384)
    InitFunctions took: 297ms
```

Comment: For starters, it's an `IllegalArgumentException` so some method gets passed bad parameters.

Comment: does the stack give any clue about in which method this happens?

Comment: The one at the top. No idea why.

Answer (score 0):

> D:\eclipseWorkspaces\AKTUELL/../runtime-EclipseApplication

That part of your command line args looks a bit iffy to me

Comment: ...i start a Self-Hosting session for the plugin and it creates the workspace runtime-EclipseApplication

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source for `ReplaceableUCharacterIterator`, it throws an `IllegalArgumentException` when it's passed a `null` in its constructor. So, something has gone missing. Probably a bug in the plugin. Could be that a file was removed that shouldn't have been, or something didn't get saved correctly in your last session. Or lots of other possibilities.

Best thing is probably to create a new workspace and start copying things in - this will very often solve problems with eclipse/plugins that just aren't worth the time investigating in detail.

Comment: well, i did create a new workspace and i copied everything ,,,,the problem seems to be somewhere else